# how to automatically rotate the image after capturing image using Camera X library?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-camerax

I am new in using camera X library. I am trying to follow the codelab from Google in [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#4)

I can show the preview and capture the image. but the problem is ......

when I capture the image in landscape, the image result will be still in portrait. I want to make it automatically rotate. if I take the image in landscape then the result should be in landscape, and if I take it in portrait then the result should be in portrait. like the camera in 'Camera' app

how to do that ?

I am using Redmi Note 7, Android 10.

the gradle I use:

```
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-beta11"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-beta11"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha18"
```

here is my code to show the preview and to capture the image

```
class CameraFragment : Fragment() {

    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
    private var cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraFragment"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
    }

    lateinit var mContext : Context
    lateinit var mActivity : FragmentActivity

   

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        mContext = context
        activity?.let { mActivity = it }

    }


    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = mActivity.externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() }
        }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else mActivity.filesDir
    }


    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(mContext)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        it.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
                    }


            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()


            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(mContext))
    }


    private fun takePhoto() {

        // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return


        // Create time-stamped output file to hold the image
        val photoFile = File(
                outputDirectory,
                SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US
                ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")

        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()


        // Set up image capture listener, which is triggered after photo has
        // been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(mContext), object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {

            override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.d("agungxxx", "2: ${exc.localizedMessage}")
                Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
            }

            override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                cameraSharedViewModel.sendImageUriPathToPreviousDestination(photoFile)
                findNavController().navigateUp()
            }
        })

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rotation of the captured image depends on [the target rotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture#getTargetRotation()) of the `ImageCapture` use case. By default, when it isn't set by the application, it is equal to `Display.getRotation()`, where `Display` is the default display at the time the `ImageCapture` use case is created.

This means that you need to updated the `ImageCapture`'s target rotation every time the display's orientation changes, e.g. when the device is physically rotated from portrait to landscape.

I'm assuming your activity has a locked orientation (?). In this case, you can use an [`OrientationEventListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener) to continuously get updates on the device's rotation, and then update the use case's target rotation accordingly.

```
val orientationEventListener = object : OrientationEventListener(this) {
    override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {
        if (orientation == OrientationEventListener.UNKNOWN_ORIENTATION) {
            return
        }

        val rotation = when (orientation) {
            in 45 until 135 -> Surface.ROTATION_270
            in 135 until 225 -> Surface.ROTATION_180
            in 225 until 315 -> Surface.ROTATION_90
            else -> Surface.ROTATION_0
        }

        imageCapture.targetRotation = rotation
    }
}
```

You should start/stop the `orientationEventListener` when the Activity's lifecycle is started/stopped, this also matches when the camera's started/stopped. You can see an example of this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/orientation-rotation).

You can also learn more about CameraX's use cases and rotation [in the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/orientation-rotation).

Comment: @Husyan Thank you very much, it solves my problem, I use the code like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcJGd.png , but could you please give info about UNKNOWN_ORIENTATION value here ? because I can't find it in the documentation as well, is that a negative integer ?

Comment: Glad to hear that. [`UNKNOWN_ORIENTATION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener#ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) is equal to -1, the listener receives when the rotation of the device cannot be determined.